# MongoDB: Sort by array index

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

I have a document with an array field that contains a list of values and I would like to sort by the first element in the array.

```
{
   field1 : "bla",
   field2 : "bla",
   field3 : "bla",
   someArray : [123, 456, 789]
}
```

I was trying to query like this:

```
db.testCollection.find({}).sort({"someArray[0]" : 1})
```

But this does not seem to have any effect and the sort gets ignored.

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the way to sort your collection by the first element of `someArray` in increasing order is:

```
db.testCollection.find().sort({"someArray.0": 1})
```

There is no need for the aggregation framework here.  You were very close!

Comment: Be interested in your thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711544/mongo-incorrectly-sorting-on-array-field/51712009#51712009 if you have any spare time?

Answer (score 0):

This thing not possible in directly mongo `find` query so you should use mongo aggregation as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$someArray"},{"$sort":{"someArray":-1}})
```

but above aggregation takes too much recurssion as it caused performance issue. So I think it should poosible to update `someArray` in sorting order and then used `find`query so it shows results in `someArray` in sorted manner. Below query update `someArray`

```
db.collectionName.update({},{"$push":{"someArray":{"$each":[],"$sort":-1}}},false,true)
```

last `true` used for updating multiple documents. When update complete then simple find query as `db.collectionName.find().pretty()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not ignoring the ascending sort, but it sorts according to min value in the each array.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33302539)