# MongoDB $sort array

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo, bulkupdate

MongoDB provides a very useful `$sort` modifier to use with the `$push` operation, but unfortunately it looks like I can only ask it to sort my elements by a **named key** - which I don't have.
Another option that could be the alternative is the sort function: `sort({'array.0': 1})`[<sup>source</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312347/mongodb-sort-by-array-index#), but what if I have an array inside an array?

My documents structure in the collection is as follows:

```
{
"_id" : 123456,
"v" : [ 
    [ 
        some id, 
        some score
    ], 
    [ 
        "456456", 
        1.5
    ], 
    [ 
        "654645", 
        43
    ],
    ...
]
}
```

And I want to sort the `v` array by the score (second element) of each child array.

So using `$sort`: I can't use a key name

```
'$push': {
    'v': {
        '$each': [[id, score]],
        '$sort': {???: -1},
    }
}
```

and using `sort()`: I can't use an array of array:

```
sort({'v.???.0': -1})
```

Is there something I'm missing, or is there another way to do this kind of sorting *without* fetching the document, sorting, and replacing? That would be a very time-consuming opeartion.
Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough question, but you really cannot do it. You can `{ $sort: -1 }` which would order on  the values of the "first" element. But for the "second" you would be better off using the same `"k"` and `"v"` structure with objects instead. Then you can `$sort: { v: -1 }` on the value. But there is no notation for the current form. Difficult to query like that as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks! I decided to change the sub-array to a document and give names to each field (id, score). For my database that will take a few hours to complete, but it's my best bet.