# Mongo incorrectly sorting on array field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to filter on an array field which unfortunately doesn't seem to be working correctly. Everything I've read suggests that this should work, and the sort is doing *something*, just not what I expected and I can't explain it.

What I'm trying to achieve is sorting on an array sub-field. I've managed to achieve most of this using the positional operator but I can't work out what the sort is doing.

```
db.getCollection('boards')
  .find({ "lastVisited.user": "AAA" }, { name: 1, "lastVisited.$" : 1 })
  .sort({ "lastVisited.0.timestamp": 1 });
```

This results in the following output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b642d2cac2f544b1d48d09a"),
    "lastVisited" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "AAA",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-18T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6845245e102f3844d2181b"),
    "lastVisited" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "AAA",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6842095e102f3844d2181a"),
    "lastVisited" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "AAA",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-19T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

The thing to note here is that the dates are ordered `18th` then `19th` then `16th` which makes no sense! Can anyone explain this?

These are the documents that I've used:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b642d2cac2f544b1d48d09a"),
    "lastVisited" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "BBB",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-04T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "AAA",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-18T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6842095e102f3844d2181a"),
    "lastVisited" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "AAA",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-19T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6845245e102f3844d2181b"),
    "lastVisited" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "AAA",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-16T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In the above document do you want to `$sort` with `ISODate("2018-08-04T00:00:00.000Z")` or `ISODate("2018-08-18T00:00:00.000Z")`? OR with always first array element?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet In the above the filter and project of `"lastVisited.$"` should ensure that there's only ever 1 item in the array. Therefore always sorting with the first array element is fine.

Comment: This is working as expected. The positional operator has no relation to sorting. Sort is done in your case based on first element of the array no matter what element positional operator returns.

Comment: You need to first `$slice` array with 0th element and then need to apply `$sort` on it... something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mgjlFn_CKlm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this currently in Mongo, as it still uses the full document (not just the projected part) to sort on. So you'll need to use the aggregation framework instead. See an open issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4451

Here's an example with aggregation, as you want your sort to happen on matched elements

```
db.getCollection('stack1').aggregate([
// Initial document match (uses index, if a suitable one is available)
{ $match: 
    { "lastVisited.user": "AAA" }
},
{ "$unwind":"$lastVisited"},
{ $match:{
    "lastVisited.user": "AAA"
}},
{ "$sort": { "lastVisited.timestamp": 1 } }    

])
```

Comment: Could you explain why? Other answers suggest you can sort on an array field - example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312347/mongodb-sort-by-array-index

Comment: The example you showed a:[1,2,3] is not an array of objects . Array needs to be flattened in mongo using aggregation for sort  to work

Comment: I'd be interested to know what it is sorting on then, as changing the sort order definitely does something (as does removing the sort). The link you sent suggests to me it should still work `Checks if tag is an array. If it is an array, it needs to choose an element from the array whose value it can assume to be the weight of particular document`

Comment: Was just going through your documents, what I saw is the `.sort()`  in your example, it is referencing just the first object of each array for sort operation. So in 1st doc it is taking `user:BBB`'s timestamp which is the smallest and so is the doc showing first in the result instead of doc-2.
Interchanging those 2 objects of doc-1 will fetch correct result.

Comment: Ah - so even though I'm excluding the `{ "user" : "BBB", "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-08-04T00:00:00.000Z") }` in the project, it's still using it to sort on? That makes sense, but is disappointing!